# Оптимизация кода на время

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Помогите с оптимизацией кода, я в этом не силён. На сайте `codewars` проходил задание и мой код работает со всеми тестами кроме `Производительности`, пишет `Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)`. Как его можно оптимизировать?

```
bool scramble(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) {
    std::string temp1{};
    std::string temp2{s1};
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < s2.size(); ++i) {
        for (unsigned long j = 0; j < temp2.size(); ++j) {
            if (s2[i] == temp2[j]) {
                temp1.push_back(s2[i]);
                temp2.erase(std::find(temp2.begin(), temp2.end(), temp2[j]));
              break;
            }
        }
    }
    return (s2 == temp1)? true : false;
}
```

Входные данные:

```
scramble("rkqodlw", "world"), Equals(true);
scramble("cedewaraaossoqqyt", "codewars"), Equals(true);
scramble("katas", "steak"), Equals(false);
scramble("scriptjavx", "javascript"), Equals(false);
scramble("scriptingjava", "javascript"), Equals(true);
scramble("scriptsjava", "javascript"), Equals(true);
scramble("javscripts", "javascript"), Equals(false);
scramble("aabbcamaomsccdd", "commas"), Equals(true);
scramble("commas", "commas"), Equals(true);
scramble("sammoc", "commas"), Equals(true);
```

Само задание [тыц](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c04b4cc56a697bb0000048/train/cpp)

Comment: Что должен делать код - нужно угадать?

Comment: Оптимизация некомментированных кодов - увлекательнейшая задача:-) Я прямо параллельно с @MBo написал:-)

Comment: @Сергей Да ладно некомментированных — все равно оптимизировать нало алгоритм, а не пытаться сэкономит на спичках... Но вот когда неизвестно, что код должен делать, то...

Comment: @Harry, Добавил входные данные и что ожидается.

Comment: @Harry Прикрепил к вопросу ссылку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я и думал, простого решения вполне достаточно:

```
bool scramble(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    std::string ss1 = s1, ss2 = s2;
    std::sort(ss1.begin(),ss1.end());
    std::sort(ss2.begin(),ss2.end());
    return std::includes(ss1.begin(),ss1.end(),ss2.begin(),ss2.end());
}
```

Главное правило — оптимизация должна начинаться с алгоритма, а не с кода...

Comment: Спасибо, об алгоритме includes не знал, пойду штудировать заново STL.

Comment: Он очень просто пишется руками; главное — отсортированность входных последовательностей.

Answer (score 0):

Codewars разрешает поменять сигнатуру, лишь бы работало, так что код Harry можно упростить до

```
bool scramble(std::string s1, std::string s2)
{
    std::sort(s1.begin(),s1.end());
    std::sort(s2.begin(),s2.end());
    return std::includes(s1.begin(),s1.end(),s2.begin(),s2.end());
}
```